Debug log shows data in list of the Controller Class but Visualforce page is not displaying anything
The debug logs of the Controller class show the correct data in the list that I have used to split (questions and answers) but while using the same to display it on the vf page it is not displaying anything. Here is the attached controller class code and the vf page code. Let me know what else needs to be done.
DecisionTreeHistoryExtension apex class
public with sharing class DecisionTreeHistoryExtension {
    public List<Decision_Tree_History__c> decisionTreeList { get; set; }
    public static Reportable_Authority__c raObj { get; set; }
   // public static List<QAEntry> qaList { get; set; }
    public DecisionTreeHistoryExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        System.debug('Inside Method');
         raObj = (Reportable_Authority__c)controller.getRecord();
        decisionTreeList = [SELECT Id, Name, Decision_Tree_Result__c, History_Field_1__c, History_Field_2__c,
                            Reason_for_Change__c, Reportable_Authority__c, User__r.Name, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate 
                            FROM Decision_Tree_History__c
                            WHERE Reportable_Authority__c = :raObj.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
    }
    public class QAEntry {
    public String Question { get; set; }
    //public String Answers { get; set; }
    public String raObj {get; set;}
    public String questions {get; set;}  
    public String answers {get; set;}
    public  List<QAEntry> qaList { get; set; }
}
    public static void splitTree(){
        
        System.debug('Inside split tree method ');
 
        List<Decision_Tree_History__c> raid = [SELECT  History_Field_1__c FROM Decision_Tree_History__c WHERE Reportable_Authority__c =: raObj.Id];
          System.debug('Raid ' + raid);
        String input;
        for (Decision_Tree_History__c ra : raid){
              System.debug('Inside for loop '+raid[0] );
              System.debug('Inside for loop '+raid[1] );
             input = raid[1].History_Field_1__c;
        }
       
        System.debug('Input String: ' + input);

    List<QAEntry> qaList = (List<QAEntry>)JSON.deserialize(input, List<QAEntry>.class);
    System.debug( ' qaList: ' + qaList);
    
    List<String> questions = new List<String>();
    List<String> answers = new List<String>();
   
    for (QAEntry qa : qaList) {
        questions.add(qa.Question);
        answers.add(qa.Answers);
    }
    for (Integer i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {
        System.debug( ' Question: ' + questions[i]);
        System.debug(' Answer: ' + answers[i]);
    }
       
}
}

DecisionTreePdf.vf
<apex:page standardController="Reportable_Authority__c" extensions="DecisionTreeHistoryExtension" action="{!splitTree}" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" renderAs="pdf" standardStylesheets="false">
        <head>
        <style>
            @page {
            margin-top: 1.6in;
            @bottom-right {
            content:"Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
            font-weight: lighter;
            font-size:8pt;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            @top-left{

            content: element(header);
            }
            @bottom-left{

            content: element(footer);
            }
            }
            div.header {
            position: running(header);
            }
            div.footer{
            position: running(footer);
            }

            body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 9px; }
            .headerCaption_us_health {font: bold 9px}
            .headerCaptionLarge {font: bold 25px;font-style:italic;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
            .headerCaptionMidium {font: bold 11px;}
            .headerCaptionSmall {font: bold 10px;}
            .headerRightFooter {vertical-align:sub;}
            .headerRightRow {line-height:20px;}
            .headerRightRowRightAlign td { line-height:20px; text-align:right;}

            .property{ font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; border:.5px solid black;vertical-align:top;}


        </style>
        
    </head>
       <div class="header">
        <table style="width:100%;text-align: left;">
            <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">
                <td  style="width:40%;vertical-align:top;padding-left: 0px;"> 
                    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PDFLogo)}" width="70%" height="70%"/>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <p class="active" href="#Company" align="center" ><h1>Decision Tree History Report</h1></p> 
            
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table  style="width : 100%;font-size:14px;-Fs-table-paginate: paginate">
             <tr  style="width : 100%;">
                                <td align="right" >
                                    {!Reportable_Authority__c.Name}
                                </td>
                               
                            </tr>       
        </table>
        <div class='container-fluid'> 
            <div style="width:100%; height:2px;background:black;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<body>
    <div class="footer" name="footer"> <span>
        <div class='container-fluid'> 
            <div style="width:100%; height:2px;background:black;"></div>
        </div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <!--<table>
        <apex:repeat value="{!decisionTreeList}" var="tree">
            <tr>
              <td><b>{Decision Tree Run By: }</b></td>
              <td>{!tree. User__r.Name}</td>
              <td><b>{Decision Tree Run At: }</b></td>
              <td>{!tree.CreatedDate}</td>
              <td><b>{Reason For Rerun: }</b></td>
              <td>{!tree.Reason_for_Change__c}</td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
          </table>-->
                               
               
    <!--<table  style="width:100%;table-layout: fixed;-fs-table-paginate: paginate;display: {!IF(decisionTreeList!=null && decisionTreeList.size>0,'table','none')}" cellspacing="0" >
             <apex:repeat value="{!decisionTreeList}" var="Vars" rendered="{!IF(decisionTreeList!=null && decisionTreeList.size>0,true,false)}">-->
                <table style="width:100% !important; border:0.5px solid black;  border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr  style=" width:100%;height:30px">
                        <th style="background-color: #dedede; width:40%;height:20%;border: 0.5px solid black;padding-left:10px;font-size:13px">Question</th>
                        <th style="background-color: #dedede; width:40%;height:20%;border: 0.5px solid black;padding-left:10px;font-size:13px">Answers</th>
                    </tr>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!qaList}" var="qa">
                        
                <tr style="width:100%; height:30px">
                    <td style="width:40%; height:20%; border: 0.5px solid black; padding-left:10px; font-size:13px;">{!qa.questions}</td>
                    <td style="width:40%; height:20%; border: 0.5px solid black; padding-left:10px; font-size:13px;">{!qa.answers}</td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
                    </table>
</body>
</apex:page>


Which list are you talking about - decisionTreeList or qaList?  Please [edit] your post to clarify and include more detail.
